# Apply on Dataframe and getting: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, copy, apply

I always have used dataframe.apply(lambda x : f(x)) like follow and suddenly, only for this specific case, I am receiving this really annoying error message. As it is encapsulated in an App and Log are seen by users. It is pretty annoying

```
df_Holdings['Price'] = df_Holdings['Price'].apply(lambda x : round(x,6))
```

The error :

> 2611: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of
>   a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

I tried also this way but received a deeper error message:

```
df_Holdings.loc[:, 'Price'] = df_Holdings.loc[:, 'Price'].apply(lambda x : round(x,6))
```

The error:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self.obj[item] = s

Is this really this row really having an issue?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing df_Holdings was created from a bigger dataframe earlier in your code, which can be dangerous.  Also no need to use lambda to round, just round the column itself without applying

Comment: 1. Yeah thats what I thought, I need to make the legacy. 2. How would write rounding then ?